# Recursive CTE with multiple children

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

i´ve got a problem with a cte im working on.

First of all i created an example showing the problem i have:

```
CREATE TABLE #ctetemp (ID int, ParentID int, Level int, Value float, Unit varchar(5), Name Varchar(150))

INSERT INTO #ctetemp (ID, ParentID, Level, Value, Unit, Name)
VALUES 
(50,21,4,7.15,'C','Name01'),
(306,106,6,7.15,'A','Name02'),
(307,106,6,2.86,'A','Name03'),
(308,106,6,7.15,'A','Name04'),
(309,106,6,14.3,'A','Name05'),
(310,106,6,2.86,'A','Name06'),
(311,106,6,2.86,'A','Name08'),
(312,107,6,14.3,'A','Name07'),
(313,107,6,28.6,'A','Name09'),
(314,107,6,28.6,'A','Name10'),
(315,107,6,34.32,'A','Name11'),
(338,112,6,28.6,'B','Name12'),
(339,112,6,14.3,'B','Name13'),
(340,112,6,14.3,'B','Name14'),
(341,112,6,14.3,'B','Name15'),
(342,113,6,71.5,'B','Name16'),
(372,118,6,14.3,'C','Name17'),
(373,118,6,14.3,'C','Name18'),
(375,118,6,14.3,'C','Name19'),
(375,118,6,42.9,'B','Name19'),
(414,122,6,14.3,'B','Name20'),
(415,122,6,14.3,'B','Name21'),
(416,122,6,14.3,'B','Name22'),
(417,122,6,14.3,'B','Name23'),
(418,122,6,14.3,'B','Name24'),
(419,122,6,14.3,'B','Name25'),
(500,131,6,7.15,'C','Name26'),
(938,193,6,7.15,'C','Name27'),
(1188,228,6,14.3,'C','Name28'),
(1285,244,6,14.3,'B','Name29'),
(1324,253,6,0,'C','Name30'),
(1327,253,6,42.9,'C','Name31'),
(1482,282,6,14.3,'C','Name32'),
(1548,1547,5,28.6,'A','Name33'),
(1561,1548,6,14.3,'A','Name34'),
(1601,106,6,28.6,'C','Name64'),
(1602,106,6,28.6,'C','Name35'),
(1603,106,6,28.6,'C','Name36'),
(1604,106,6,14.3,'C','Name37'),
(1689,118,6,14.3,'C','Name38'),
(1690,118,6,7.15,'C','Name62'),
(1819,131,6,7.15,'C','Name39'),
(1820,131,6,7.15,'C','Name40'),
(2281,193,6,7.15,'C','Name27'),
(2303,196,6,21.45,'A','Name41'),
(2304,196,6,28.6,'A','Name42'),
(2518,228,6,7.15,'C','Name63'),
(2539,231,6,7.15,'A','Name43'),
(3642,1548,6,42.9,'A','Name44'),
(21,10,3,0,NULL,'Name45'),
(106,36,5,0,NULL,'Name46'),
(107,37,5,0,NULL,'Name47'),
(112,40,5,0,NULL,'Name48'),
(113,41,5,0,NULL,'Name49'),
(118,44,5,0,NULL,'Name50'),
(122,46,5,0,NULL,'Name51'),
(131,50,5,0,NULL,'Name52'),
(228,80,5,0,NULL,'Name53'),
(253,93,5,0,NULL,'Name54'),
(282,102,5,0,NULL,'Name55'),
(40,17,4,0,NULL,'Name56'),
(41,17,4,0,NULL,'Name57'),
(44,19,4,0,NULL,'Name58'),
(46,19,4,0,NULL,'Name61'),
(17,8,3,0,NULL,'Name59'),
(19,9,3,0,NULL,'Name60')

;WITH CTE AS
(
   -- define the "anchor" query - select the chosen forum
   SELECT 
      f.id, f.Value, f.id as RootID, f.Unit, f.Level
   FROM #ctetemp f
   WHERE Level = 3
   UNION ALL
   -- select the child rows
   SELECT 
    f.id, f.value, cte.RootID, f.Unit, f.Level
    FROM #ctetemp f
    INNER JOIN CTE on f.ParentID = CTE.ID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE Unit IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID

DROP TAble #ctetemp
```

As you can se i´ve got a table which can contain more than 1 entry per ID. It is a list of answers by multiple users. I want to group these answers and sum their values in a later step by level and unit. There can be multiple users per unit, and each user can answer all questions, if that makes sense :). There is an undefined count of units and an undefinded count of users for each unit.

In the current script, all the answers from unit A get lost. I think i would need LEFT JOIN in the CTE, but i can't (as it is forbidden in the recursive part).

Any help would be appreciated

Kind regards
Lucas

Comment: I don't quite understand your example data. Last row `19` has a parent_id `9`... that I don't see.

Comment: Also, since you want to perform a JOIN I assume there's a foreign key between `PARENT_ID` and `ID`. But I don't see how can it be added explicitly. Can you add it, please? I think it's important to get a clean model first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you over simplified the example data but the query is right not to include unit `A`.

According to the example data all those nodes are not connected to anything. They are just dangling branches.

For example:

- 'A': 306 -> 106 -> 36 (that doesn't exist).
- 'A': 3642 -> 1548 -> 1547 (that doesn't exist).
- 'A': 2304 -> 196 (that doesn't exist).

There's no way to get to any node 'A' from the rest of the tree.